# How to create an array of all letters in the alphabet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to create an array of capital letters using a formula for use within other lookup functions?

I want to use a formula to create an array like this:

{"A","B",..,"Z"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by combining `CHAR` with `SEQUENCE`.

A horizontal array:

```
=CHAR(SEQUENCE(1,26,65))
```

A vertical array:

```
=CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,1,65))
```

The call to `SEQUENCE` creates an array of 26 numbers from 65 to 90. By passing this array into the `CHAR` function, each number is converted into the capital letter equivalent, starting with `CHAR(65)=A`

Answer (score 2):

If one does not have Office 365 and its dynamic arrays.  To create an array of Capital Letters in another formula we can use:

```
INDEX(CHAR(ROW($65:$90)),)
```

Or

```
INDEX(CHAR(COLUMN($BM:$CL)),)
```

These will return an array of the letters to another formula.